# What is a "window system" in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, operating-system

In the documentation of `QApplication::event()` method is said:

> The main event loop receives events from the window system and
>   dispatches these to the application widgets

What is a window system? Is it the same as operating system?

Comment: A window system is just one of many things that an operating system may manage.

Comment: The windowing system is the graphical user interface framework which manages windows, widgets, events, and interfaces. This sits atop the operating system, which manages processes, memory, filesystems and drivers.